# Awk and head not identifying columns properly

Tags: shell, awk, sed, head

Here is my code that I want to use to separate 3 columns from hist.txt into 2 separate files, hist1.dat with first and second column and hist2.dat with first and third column. The columns in hist.txt may be separated with more than one space. I want to save in histogram1.dat and histogram2.dat the first n lines until the last nonzero value.

The script creates histogram1.dat correct, but histogram2.dat contains all the lines from hist2.dat.

hist.txt is like :
http://pastebin.com/JqgSKZrP

```
#!bin/bash

sed 's/\t/ /g' hist.txt | awk '{print $1 " " $2;}' > hist1.dat
sed 's/\t/ /g' hist.txt | awk '{print $1 " " $3;}' > hist2.dat

head -n $( awk 'BEGIN {last=1}; {if($2!=0) last=NR};END {print last}' hist1.dat) hist1.dat > histogram1.dat
head -n $( awk 'BEGIN {last=1}; {if($2!=0) last=NR};END {print last}' hist2.dat) hist2.dat > histogram2.dat
```

What is the cause of this problem?  Might it be due to some special restriction with `head`?

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, your first sed | awk can be reduced into `awk '{print $1, $2}' hist.txt`

Answer (score 0):

For your first histogram, try

```
awk '$2 ~ /000000/{exit}{print $1, $2}' hist.txt
```

and for your second:

```
awk '$3 ~ /000000/{exit}{print $1, $3}' hist.txt
```

Hope I understood you correctly...

Comment: Eventually I used : awk '{for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {printf("%d ",$i);}}{printf("\n") ;}' hist.txt > $dir/hist1.dat                and then I could simply compare like                              awk 'BEGIN {last=1}; { for(i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { if($i !=0) last=NR;} };END {print last}' $dir/hist1.dat .   I used this solution, because the number of columns can change. Your solution would be OK, if the histogram wouldn't start with 000000. But since I need the first part for reference, I only have to cut the tailing 0-s.